# Skype for Business/Lync 2013 - Wrong Display Names

Tags: lync, lync-2013, skype, skype-for-business-2016

Recently we've been noticing an issue where when searching for a user in Skype For Business/Lync 2013, a different user will show up in the search results.  Doing some research, this seems to be related to "proxy addresses" as I notice the user that shows up incorrectly in place of the actual user (we're searching for) has their email address added as an alias (smtp) address in Exchange.  So we search for user A, but User B's name shows up.  User B's email address (an ex-employee that isn't in Exchange anymore) is added as an alias (smtp) address as part of User A's email addresses in Exchange.

The link below seems to describe our issue, but we're running Lync server 2013 and not 2010.  Is there anyway to fix this issue for Lync Server 2013?

http://www.markc.me.uk/markc/Blog/Entries/2012/8/8_Lync_showing_wrong_name_for_a_user.html

Answer (score 0):

The resolution is the same for Lync Server 2013. Everything in the article you supplied applies to Lync Server 2013.

The only difference is that you need to use the [Lync 2013 Resource Kit](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36821).